# Can I use a NETGEAR FVG318 to provide a wireless access point for a wired network?

Tags: networking, netgear

Got one of these in the closet but I am no networking guru. Can it be used in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you may want to turn off the NAT and firewall portions.